# Subtracting two clock times in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to subtract two columns of a pandas data frame which contain normal clock times as strings, but somehow I am getting struck.

I have tried converting each column to datetime using pandas.datetime, but still the subtraction doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = ["12:30","5:30"]
df['B'] = ["19:30","9:30"]

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A']).dt.time
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B']).dt.time

df['time_diff'] = df['B'] - df['A']

I am expecting the actual time difference between two clock times.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should using `to_timedelta`

```
df['A'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['A']+':00')
df['B'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['B']+':00')
df['time_diff'] = df['B'] - df['A']
df
Out[21]: 
         A        B time_diff
0 12:30:00 19:30:00  07:00:00
1 05:30:00 09:30:00  04:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following method. This also worked for me. Divide by 3600 to get the time in hours.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame()
 df['A'] = ["12:30","5:30"]
 df['B'] = ["19:30","9:30"]
 df['time_diff_minutes'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['B']) - 
 pd.to_datetime(df['A'])).astype('timedelta64[s]')/60
 df['time_diff_hours'] = df['time_diff_minutes']/60
 df

Out[161]: 
       A      B  time_diff_minutes  time_diff_hours
0  12:30  19:30              420.0              7.0
1   5:30   9:30              240.0              4.0
```